# Find the associated matrix

Tags: real-analysis

So I was working on this problem and I don't know how to continue. If someone could explain to me what to do next that would be wonderful.

For a point $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, define $\mathbf{T}(x,y,z)$ to be the point on the plane $P = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;| \; x+y+z =0 \}$ that is closest to $(x,y,z)$.  Show that the mapping $\mathbf{T}:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is linear and find the $3 \times 3$ matrix associated with this mapping.

My Solution: I'm pretty sure I need to find a projection for this one. So I have $\left \|\frac{\langle x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0 \rangle \langle 1,1,1 \rangle}{| \langle 1,1,1 \rangle|}\right \| =\sqrt{\frac{3((x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2)}{3}} = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2}$ After this I am lost on how it is used to know the associated matrix. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

the projection of $(x, y, z)^T$ onto the line $(1,1,1)$ is $\frac{(x+y+z)}3(1,1,1).$
therefore the projection of $(x,y,z)^T$ onto the plane is $$(x,y,z)^T - \frac{(x+y+z)}3(1,1,1) = \frac13(2x-y-z,-x+2y-z, -x-y+2z)^T.$$  the associated matrix is $$\frac13\pmatrix{2&-1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\-1&-1&2}. $$